# Reverse Integer

Tags: java, reverse

Reverse digits of an integer.

Example1: x = 123, return 321
Example2: x = -123, return -321

I was trying to use the code below to solve the integer reverse problem. But when I convert the int to a string and then convert the string back to int, there is an error. I am wondering if the memory allocation limiting this method.

The error is Line 4: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int

```
public class Solution {
    public long reverse(int x) {
        String input = String.valueOf(x);
        char[] num = input.toCharArray();
        StringBuffer reverse = new StringBuffer();
        if(x<0){
            reverse.append("-");
            for(int i=num.length-1;i>0;i--){
                reverse.append(num[i]);
            }
        }else{
            for(int i=num.length-1;i>=0;i--){
                reverse.append(num[i]);
            }
        }
        return Long.parseLong(reverse.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Please post such information together with your question.

Comment: It would help to know what kind of error there is... ;-)

Comment: hi! can you show what error you get?

Comment: *"The error is Line 4: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int"* The code in the question does not produce that error.

Comment: Give us a specific example of when the error occurs.

Answer (score 3):

It does what you have asked for.

```
public static long reverseInteger(int n){
    String answer = "";
    if (n == Integer.MIN_VALUE)
        return -8463847412L;
    boolean negative = false;
    if (n < 0) {
        negative = true;
        n = -n;
    }
    while (n > 0) {
        answer += (n % 10);
        n = n/10;
    }
    long toReturn = Long.parseLong(answer);
    return (negative) ? -toReturn : toReturn;
}
```

The `static` keyword is optional, of course.
It depends on how you use it.

Comment: Why are you using the boxed types `Integer` and `Long` instead of `int` and `long`?

Comment: Cause I needed it once and have not edited it. Wait 20 seconds ;)

Comment: Try calling reverseInteger(Integer.MIN_VALUE)    ;-)

Comment: Thank you, Klitos. I did not realize the overflow at first... there is no symmetry.

Comment: I know, it can look a bit strange that `-(Integer.MIN_VALUE) == Integer.MIN_VALUE` !

Comment: Did you mean: `-(Integer.MIN_VALUE) != Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

Comment: No, both MIN. Try it for yourself! `System.out.println(-(Integer.MIN_VALUE) == Integer.MIN_VALUE);` ==> prints "true"

Comment: Great, this is due to this overflow and this clock-like nature.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you are getting is probably due to somewhere else in your code; perhaps you are assigning the value returned by `reverse()` (which is a long) to an `int` variable.

However, there is unnecessary inefficiency in your code. You are creating a `String`, only to re-parse it back to a number. The following code returns a reversed number without using any strings at all:

```
public static long reverse(int n){
    long r = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        r *= 10;
        r += (n % 10);
        n /= 10;
    }

    return r;
}
```

Note that this method works correctly for negative numbers too, without having to check for them specially.

This method works for all possible `int` values.

Comment: Hardcoding cases like `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is not a wrong way to go, since thinking costs ;)

Comment: Actually, my first version needed to process Integer.MIN_VALUE specially, but my latest edit works for all possible int values including Integer.MIN_VALUE. @GrzegorzGórkiewicz

Comment: School-like solution (which is not bad). Another option is to play with strings.

Comment: Will give you an upvote for the `Integer.MIN_VALUE` case ;)

Answer (score -1):

Something like this works:

```
public long reverse(int x) {
    String input = String.valueOf(x); //123
    long result = Long.parseLong(new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString());
    return result; //321
}
```

Comment: It has to return a long because an int, when reversed, could be a number larger than can fit in an int.

Comment: That now probably does what it should, but I would suspect it might be considered "cheating" because you are just calling `reverse()` - the question was probably meant to see how the candidate could do the reversing themselves.

Comment: It seems like what I wanted it to be but I didn't consider the case like 320. I can't convert it to 023 but 23. So may be reversing a number by convert it to  string is not a good idea.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to preserve leading zeros in a primitive type like long or int. Someone with more knowledge can correct me if I'm wrong though. I'm curious myself

Comment: @KyleChen what do you want reverse(320) to return? If you want "023", then it needs to return a String, not a long. If you want it to return "23", then these answers (including mine) do that.